# Tweenmax.to is defined in code, but in browers i got error messages which isn't defined

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, particles, gsap

I am trying to make particle with Tweenmax.to which is introduced here : https://youtu.be/eD3qUfc5r5k ( 9:02 )

I just followed this and I think it is defined but for some reason, I got message : it isn't defined.
Since these coding is too complicated and nested in many lines, I hardly recognize what a problem is.

What I've tried is to pull out tweenmax.to and var particle outside of "if" statement, but it didn't work and I don't think it is a problem.

```
                TweenMax.to(particle, particle.speed, {
                    x1: particle.x0,
                    y1: particle.y0,
                    delay: y / 30,
                    ease: Elastic.easeOut

                });

                particles.push(particle);
            }
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

What I expected is just showing up the images like the youtube video. Other than replay button, nothing shows up ;/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We've a guide [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it would be good if you could read it and adjust your question a bit: Add important code from the video and remove the video if it's not required anymore, the length is nearly 10 min, you can't expect others to watch it to answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what is not defined? If you mean TweenMax, did you reference it in your code? For example you can put this tag before the javascript that is using TweenMax `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you. You solved the problem

Comment: I am glad that this helped you :) Good luck!